# Finding collaborators to work on projects

Tags: project-management

I'm wondering what are good ways to find people you can work with on indie projects.
Is there anywhere some sort of list of game developer forums ? Or if it doesn't exist, what websites would you advice for that matter ?

PS : I know the question may sound a little off-topic, but I think it actually relates to project management, sorry if it is not the case.

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/page/index.html This is one of many popular game dev communities online.

Comment: The TIGSource forums are awesome for that: http://forums.tigsource.com/

Comment: Thanks for TIGSource, I didn't know about it.
About gamedev.net, I thought memberships weren't free, but they actually are.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Seeing the other question and the answer it gets, it is more about "how to convince programmers to come" than "where should I look for teammates".